# 404 page in production doesn't work for gatsby website

Tags: gatsby

404 page of gatsby doesn't work. I created a 404 page in `src/pages/404.js`.

I expect my customised 404 page to be there in production but I just got a 404 Not Found error (nginx).

Why 404 page I created is not showed in production??

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by docker configuration.

```
  {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
  }
```